# Application crashes when loading a GeoFire query into RecyclerView

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview, geofire

I am developing a location based chat application as a final assignment, but have one bug that I cannot figure out how to fix by myself. Currently, I intend to load all profiles within a certain radius into a recyclerview, and display only these profiles to the current user.

The recycler view is working fine and displays every user in my Firebase database, until I add the GeoFire query to limit the users that appear only to those within the 2km radius. All user latitudes and longitudes are being updated successfully to the database, so I don't think that this is where the problem originates.

When i run the app and it crashes, I get this exception in the LogCat:

**"java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'double android.location.Location.getLatitude()' on a null object reference"**

This is confusing me, as none of the current users in my database have a null value stored for either their longitude or latitude.

So my main question is, how can I get only the users within 2km of the current user to populate my recyclerview, without the application crashing?

[Database structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eToVa.png)

The current source code:

```
public class FindChatters extends Fragment {

private RecyclerView mUsersList;
private View mMainView;
private DatabaseReference mUsersDatabase;
private FirebaseUser mCurrentUser;
private LatLng myCurrentLocation;
private String mUserFound;
private static final int RADIUS = 2;
Location mLastLocation;

public FindChatters() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    mMainView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_find_chatters, container, false);

    mUsersDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");

    mCurrentUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

    mUsersList = (RecyclerView) mMainView.findViewById(R.id.users_list);
    mUsersList.setHasFixedSize(true);
    mUsersList.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));

    return mMainView;

}

//RETRIEVE DATA IN REALTIME
@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    startListening();

}

public void startListening() {
    Query query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").limitToLast(50);

    FirebaseRecyclerOptions<Users> options = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Users>().setQuery(query, Users.class).build();

    FirebaseRecyclerAdapter adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Users, UserViewHolder>(options) {
        @Override
        public UserViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            // CREATE NEW INSTANCE OF VIEWHOLDER, USING CUSTOM LAYOUT (R.LAYOUT.MESSAGE)
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                    .inflate(R.layout.users_single_layout, parent, false);

            return new UserViewHolder(view);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onBindViewHolder(final UserViewHolder holder, final int position, final Users model) {

            // // //

            //RETRIEVE CURRENT USERS LAT/LONG TO FIND USERS NEARBY

            String userID = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
            DatabaseReference myLoc = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Geo");
            final GeoFire geoFire = new GeoFire(myLoc);
            geoFire.setLocation(userID, new GeoLocation(mLastLocation.getLatitude(), mLastLocation.getLongitude()));

            myCurrentLocation = new LatLng(mLastLocation.getLatitude(), mLastLocation.getLongitude());

            //RETRIEVE USERS ONLY FROM WITHIN A SPECIFIED RADIUS TO THE CURRENT USER
            DatabaseReference findNearby = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Geo");
            GeoFire geoFire2 = new GeoFire(findNearby);
            //QUERY ALL NEARBY USERS IN THE DATABASE WITHIN 2KM OF CURRENT USER LAT/LONG
            final GeoQuery geoQuery = geoFire2.queryAtLocation(new GeoLocation(myCurrentLocation.latitude, myCurrentLocation.longitude), RADIUS);

            //QUERY TO RETRIEVE CLOSET USERS
            geoQuery.addGeoQueryEventListener(new GeoQueryEventListener() {

                //IF ANY USERS FOUND WITHIN RADIUS - ON KEY ENTERED IS CALLED
                @Override
                public void onKeyEntered(String key, GeoLocation location) {

                    if (geoQuery != null)   {

                        mUserFound = key;

                        //BIND CHAT OBJECT TO CHATHOLDER
                        holder.setName(model.name);
                        holder.setUserStatus(model.status);
                        holder.setUserOnline(model.online);
                        holder.setUserImage(getContext(), model.image);

                        //CLICK ON A USER PROFILE TO ACCESS THEIR INFORMATION OR INITIATE CHAT
                        final String user_id = getRef(position).getKey();

                        //RETRIEVE CURRENT USER ID
                        String current_uid = mCurrentUser.getUid();

                        //PREVENT USER FROM BEING ABLE TO INITIATE A CONVERSATION WITH THEMSELF
                        if (!user_id.equals(current_uid)) {

                            holder.mView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(View view) {

                                    Intent profileIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), ProfileActivity.class);
                                    profileIntent.putExtra("user_id", user_id);
                                    startActivity(profileIntent);

                                }
                            });

                        } else {

                            holder.setName("You");
                            holder.setUserStatus("Tap someone to say hello!");

                        }


                    } else {

                        //CREATE TEXTVIEW TO INFORM USER THAT NO NEARBY USERS ARE PRESENT

                    }

                }

                @Override
                public void onKeyExited(String key) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onKeyMoved(String key, GeoLocation location) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onGeoQueryReady() {

                }

                @Override
                public void onGeoQueryError(DatabaseError error) {

                }
            });

            // // //

        }

    };
    mUsersList.setAdapter(adapter);
    adapter.startListening();

}
```

I am still pretty new to coding, so I really appreciate any replies or help. Thanks!

Android Studio v3.1.3

Comment: `mLastLocation` is never initialised hence the issue

Comment: Thank you I will post if the code is working once initialised.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you initialise `mLastLocation`. I can see that you are retrieving lat  and lng from it but was never initialised

Comment: Ah thank you, I will post back whether the code is working successfully once I have initialised it.